# How to assign a logarithmic scale to y axis in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
var data1 = {
        labels: JSON.parse('<?php echo JSON_encode($bioc_months);?>'),
        datasets: [{
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                data: 1000,
                900,
                90,
                200,
                1020
            }, {
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                data: 600,
                456,
                20,
                2,
                900
            ]
        };

        var opt1 = {
            canvasBordersWidth: 3,
            canvasBordersColor: "#205081",
            scaleOverride: true,
            scaleSteps: 6,
            scaleStepWidth: log2,
            scaleStartValue: 0,
            scaleLabel: "<%=value%>",
            legend: true,
            inGraphDataShow: true,
            annotateDisplay: true,
            inGraphDataShow: false,
            annotateDisplay: true,
            animationEasing: "easeOutBounce",
            graphTitleFontSize: 18
        };

        var myBarChart1 = new Chart(ctx1).Bar(data1, opt1);
```

Comment: Pretty violent "question" which is only code.

Comment: You should really consider to add more information instead of just pushing the code here.

Answer (score 23):

You can assign logarithmic scale to y-axis as below:

```
yAxes: [{
    scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'LABEL',
    },
    type: 'logarithmic',
    position: 'left',
    ticks: {
         min: 0.1, //minimum tick
         max: 1000, //maximum tick
         callback: function (value, index, values) {
             return Number(value.toString());//pass tick values as a string into Number function
         }
    },
    afterBuildTicks: function (chartObj) { //Build ticks labelling as per your need
        chartObj.ticks = [];
        chartObj.ticks.push(0.1);
        chartObj.ticks.push(1);
        chartObj.ticks.push(10);
        chartObj.ticks.push(100);
        chartObj.ticks.push(1000);
    }
}]
```

Comment: I think your callback method is wrong. The parameter `value` is numeric, and it should return a `string`. This basically allows you to rename values like `1000000` to `"1M"`. You can also just return `null` if you don't want a label for that value. The `afterBuildTicks` is redundant from what I have tested. _(I am not sure if it even works, because I cannot retrieve it in the documentation neither)_. Having said that, it works fine without it, the rest of your answer helped me a lot. Anyway, the callback method is crucial if you don't want labels like `"2e5"` to represent values like `200000`

Comment: Just wanted to say that I ended up using afterBuildTicks to dynamically generate the log values for the range I needed based on evolving datasets. I used the ticks callback to make the numbers toLocaleString()'d, adding commas for large multiples of ten to make them readable. So, it isn't redundant.

Answer (score 14):

As @user2722127 pointed out, the essence is to put the type on `"logarithmic"`.

If you only take care of that, then you will end up with awkward labels in scientific format (e.g. 200000 = "2e5"). I personally prefer them a little more human.
So, the callback method actually converts `numeric` data values to `string` label values.

*Note: the callback will not be called for all values in your dataset. It will just be called for the auto-generated ticks. In my case that was enough. Nevertheless, there may be too much labels. So to limit the number of labels, I simply return `null` for all unwanted label values.*

```
yAxes: [{
    type: 'logarithmic',
    ticks: {
         min: 1,
         max: 1000000,
         callback: function (value, index, values) {
             if (value === 1000000) return "1M";
             if (value === 100000) return "100K";
             if (value === 10000) return "10K";
             if (value === 1000) return "1K";
             if (value === 100) return "100";
             if (value === 10) return "10";
             if (value === 1) return "1";
             return null;
         }
    }
}]
```

[image: result]

*Note: the screenshot above shows a chart with a 0-point on its scale. That's actually incorrect. As you can see in the above source code, I later modified the minimum value to be 1. I had to do so, because in later version of chart.js charts actually were seriously messed up and sometimes drawn underneath the chart. And it was all due to a 0-tick. Actually from a mathematical point of view, a logarithmic scale cannot really have a 0-tick. So, it makes more sense to just start at 1 or 0.001 for example. But not 0.*

## EDIT:

The following is not strictly necessary, but may possibly improve performance.

If you want more control on the created ticks, you can provide an `afterBuildTicks` property. ( Which is very similar to what is provided in the answer of @user2722127 .) In this example, it just replaces the content of the ticks array of the chart object with different ticks.

```
  afterBuildTicks = (chartObj) => {
      const ticks = [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000];
      chartObj.ticks.splice(0, chartObj.ticks.length);
      chartObj.ticks.push(...ticks);
  }
```

You just add this function as a property to the `yAxis` element, along with the other properties.

```
yAxes: [{
    type,
    ticks,
    afterBuildTicks
}]
```

Comment: Does your example callback expect those values to be included in the dataset? If not, good chance null will be returned quite often.

Comment: @bvj it's already in the answer, but maybe not clear enough. The callback is not called for the values of the dataset, but for the "ticks" of your axis. If you want to prefilter or just set your own ticks, you can provide an additional `afterBuildTicks` function to the yAxis.

Comment: @bvj I added an example.

Comment: message from the future:  I am migrating to highcharts : less code, more features, works better with angular too.

Answer (score 9):

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-logarithmic-scale

[image]

> Logarithmic Scale
>
> The logarithmic scale is use to chart numerical data. It can be placed
>   on either the x or y axis. As the name suggests, logarithmic
>   interpolation is used to determine where a value lies on the axis.